# Percentage height in CSS, how to make it the same height as the parent

Tags: html, css

I am hoping you can help me solve this problem in css.

### The problem

- Let's say we have three divs
- One parent and two children.
- There are three p in the first child, and one p in the second, which means the first child looks taller than the second.
- I then set these two children to float to left and right respectively.
- These two children are no longer in the normal float, so the height of parent div becomes 0.

However, if I set display:flow-root; in parent div, it will be as tall as the first child div. Then I set the height of the second child to be 100% of its parent.
But the height of the second child does not grow.

### The Question

- How does it not grow?
- How can I make it 100% height of its parent? Looking forward to some explaination. Below is the code and picture.

```css
.parent {
  display: block flow-root;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  background: lime;
}

.child2 {
  float: right;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>abcd</p>
    <p>efg</p>
    <p>hij</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <p>abcd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDRKA.png)

### No flex solution please

It is pretty simple to solve this using flexbox, but I want to know how to solve it without flexbox, so please dont post flexbox solution here.
What exactly I want is that I want the first div to stretch the parent div's height and the second child div would be following that height.

Comment: You can't. Not if you want the second child div to float.

Comment: *It is pretty simple to solve this using flexbox* --> that's **the** solution (or CSS grid). Don't try to find something else, there is no other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Without flex

- This is a horrible solution compared to flex but it works. Caveat is that it only works when `child` div is taller than `child2`
- Uses `position: relative` & `position: absolute` to get the child2 div over to the right and take up the full height. [MDN position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.child, .child2 {
    width: max-content;
}

.child {
    background: lime;
}

.child2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <p>abcd</p>
        <p>efg</p>
        <p>hij</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        <p>abcd</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### The solution you don't want

As [Temani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) mentioned in the above comment the best solution is to use [**flex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). I know you don't want it but if anyone else finds there way here with the same question as you they mind want to use flex.

### Solution with flex

```css
.parent {
    background-color: aqua;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.child {
    background: lime;
}
.child2 {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <p>abcd</p>
        <p>efg</p>
        <p>hij</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        <p>abcd</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Explanation of CSS

- `justify-content: space-between`: Items are evenly distributed in the line; first item is on the start line, last item on the end line.
- `align-items: stretch;`: Stretches the child to the height of the parent

### Resource

- [CSS tricks guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/): A great and popular resource to get familiar with flex properties